# Does SQL0289N affect other users?

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I am getting this error:

`com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.SqlException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-289, SQLSTATE=57011, SQLERRMC=XXX32KTMP, DRIVER=3.51.90`

on a select statement that has a couple of dozen sub-selects.

SQL0289N usually means the current table space size is not enough for allocating new pages for new data.

I want to modify my select such that it does not use as much table space.

While modifying the select I presumably will get this error several more times until I am successful.

My questions are:
A) Does this error only affect my select?
B) Are other users of the database more like to have a problem because I am running this select?

The context of those questions is that I want to know if I have to move my work to a different database to be reasonably sure that I am not impacting other users.

I am wary because the error description is not clear if it is running out of memory that is shared between all users, or memory that is only allocated to my connection.

Note: I am NOT asking how to increase table space or what this error means.  I am NOT asking for help modifying my select (hence, I did not show the select). Any answers to that effect would be off topic.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how exactly the tablespace in question is defined and why your query needs it it is hard to give you a definite answer.

In the best case the error affects any SQL statement, executed in any session, that requires the use of the same tablespace, especially if it is a system temporary tablespace.

In the worst case, e.g. if it is an SMS tablespace and it shares the file system with other tablespaces and log files, it might even bring the entire DB2 instance down.

Tuning your statement in a different database does not necessarily mean that it will resolve the problem in the original database.

Comment: is the SQLSTATE=57011 and the table space name of XXX32KTMP a clue to any of the missing information?  The XXX32KTMP name where XXX is the name of the database.

Comment: No they are not. You explicitly excluded all clues as off-topic.

Comment: Are all table spaces shared between connections?  If all are shared, then my question is answered: A full table space will likely affect other users.

Comment: Tablespaces are "shared between connections" as much as the databases itself is "shared between connections", because they constitute the physical structure of the database. They may share the same file system, in which case growth of one may affect the others. I suggest you read about some of the DB2 concepts.